# Why 1PI graphs are enough to discuss renormalizability?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In quantum field theory, S-matrix elements are connected to observables which we can measure experimentally.
In order to work with a well-defined theory, we need to remove all the divergences and renormalize fields and couplings.

In general, to compute an S-matrix element for a specific process, we need to compute all possible (connected) graphs which reproduce the process. 
However, to discuss the renormalizability of a theory we just consider 1PI graphs.

Can you tell me why we look at 1PI graphs and not to the other non-1PI graphs to check if a theory is renormalizable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because any correlation function $G_i$ can be decomposed into (simpler) irreducible functions $\Gamma_i$. For example, the two point function is
$$
G_2(p)=\frac{1}{\Gamma_2(p)}
$$
, the three point function is
$$
G_3(p_1,p_2,p_3)=G_2(p_1)G_2(p_2)G_2(p_3)\Gamma_3(p_1,p_2,p_3)
$$
, the four point function is
$$
G_4(p_1,\cdots,p_4)=G_2(p_1)\cdots G_2(p_4)\Gamma_4(p_1,\cdots,p_4)+G_2(p_1)\cdots \Gamma_3(p_1,p_2,p_3)\cdots G_2(p_4)+\cdots
$$

In other words, if the irreducible functions $\Gamma_i$ are finite, all correlation functions $G_i$ are finite as well. And the finiteness of irreducible functions is *way* easier to prove (simpler combinatorics, fewer diagrams, no subdivergences, etc).

Comment: I understand this is an old question but I have the same question. I get your answer. Just one clarification. Are these $\Gamma_i$ (that you wrote) irreducible vertex functions i.e., the sum of 1PI diagrams? @AFT

Comment: @SRS yes. If you have any question, feel free to ask, and I'll try to address it.